# What is the difference in these two snippets?

Tags: magento-1.7, cart

Is there really a difference between these two code snippets?

First, getting the cart_count using getItemsCount()

```
    $cart_count = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getItemsCount();
```

and this one getting the cart, first:

```
    $cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart();
    $cart_count = $cart->getItemsCount();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference.

`Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart();`  and `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')` are the same thing.

If you take a look in `Mage_Checkout_Helper_Cart::getCart` you will see that the only thing it does is `return Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');`.

So, I guess, if you want to be picky about it the first method is fastest by a few [Plank time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_time) units but the result is the same. Second method is a wrapper for the first one.